# Android Studio add drawable (vectrodrawable) to ic_menu

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying to add some Buttons with drawables to my App in Android Studio.

I found the drawables:
ic_menu_camera,
ic_menu_gallery,
ic_menu_manage,
ic_menu_send,
ic_menu_share and
ic_menu_slideshow.

Is there an option to get drawables like "_home, _screen_mirrowing"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own home and screen_mirrowing images ,You will get option on Right click of mouse on project explorer area New->Asset-> 
* give your customized image name there

Answer (score 0):

You can basically add any image to your project.  Right-click on `res -> drawable`, and choose `New -> Image Asset` or `New -> Vector Asset`.  Then you could choose `Icon Type` as `Action Bar and Tab Icons`, then in the `Asset Type` choose `Image`.  Next put in the path to the image you want.  For me, I found `ic_menu_camera`, etc., in the folder `C:\Users\myUserId\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\data\res\drawable-xhdpi`

Android Studio will then create image resources in your project for various sizes.  For details, please see [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-image-to-drawable-folder-in-android-studio/#:~:text=1%20Open%20Android%20Studio%20and%20go%20to%20the,android%20studio%20automatically%20created%20the%20different-sized%20images.%20](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-image-to-drawable-folder-in-android-studio/#:%7E:text=1%20Open%20Android%20Studio%20and%20go%20to%20the,android%20studio%20automatically%20created%20the%20different-sized%20images.%20)

Or

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-svg-psd-images-to-vector-drawable-file-in-android-studio/?ref=rp